# Getting at `sysdate` when using standard verbs i dplyr/dbplyr

Tags: r, dbplyr

Using the standard `dbplyr` verbs, how can I access and use the database's `sysdate` value, such as for filtering, etc.?

As an example, how do I do, without doing raw SQL (but with select/filter/mutate verbs) do:

```
select sysdate from dual
```

Trying this, on a [Vertica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertica#Products) database:

```r
dual_tbl <-
    tbl(con, "dual")

dual_tbl %>%
    select(sysdate)

#> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Column `sysdate` doesn't exist.
```

I really want to access the database's `sysdate` and compare it against other columns in the database that are timestamps.

Comment: Does `sysdate` here relate to the database or to the server?  Would that differ from `Sys.Date()`?
 https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/SYSDATE.htm

Comment: @JonSpring The database.  It's what the sql `sysdate` reserved word that gets what the database thinks is the current datetime.  That may under the covers call the server datetime, depending on implementation... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

It was asked and answered in *[Getting the database sysdate using dbplyr verb](https://community.rstudio.com/t/getting-the-database-sysdate-using-dbplyr-verb/118108/2)*.

A short answer from there: use the `lubridate` library, and the `now()` or `today()` function.